# hibernate @onetomany bidirectinal mapping doesn't map data correctly

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I have two entity classes.User and FriendStatus.Friend status keeps data about friend requests that have come from another users.

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@XmlRootElement
public class User implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "acceptor")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Message> acceptedMessages;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "sender")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Message> sentMessages;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;

@Column(name = "phone_number")
private String phoneNumber;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<User> friends;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="requestAcceptor")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("requestAcceptor")
private List<FriendStatus> acceptedFriendRequests;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "requestSender")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("requestSender")
private List<FriendStatus> sentFriendRequests;

@Column(name = "profile_status")
private String profileStatus;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "activation_status")
private UserActivationStatus activationStatus;
```

FriendStatus:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FRIEND_STATUS")
public class FriendStatus implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long Id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="request_sender_id")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("sentFriendRequests")
private User requestSender;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="request_acceptor_id")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("acceptedFriendRequests")
private User requestAcceptor;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "request_status")
private FriendRequestStatus friendRequestStatus;
```

When i first time save FriendStatus object to the database it works fine.But when i save object second time with the same requestAcceptor object,hibernate deletes previous id from request_acceptor_id column and writes it to the new row.HELP ME PLEASE.

EDIT:

This is the method which i save my object to db.

```
public T create(T object) {
T  objectFromDB = object;
Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction transaction = null;
try {
    transaction = (Transaction) session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(object);        
    transaction.commit();

} catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (session != null){
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    session.close();
}
return objectFromDB;
}
```

This is the method where i call create method:

```
public void sendFriendRequest(FriendStatus object) {
    FriendStatus status = fDao.create(object);//fDao is the object from Dao class which includes create method.
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sendFriendRequest",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String sendFriendRequest(@RequestBody FriendStatus status) {
    serviceUser.sendFriendRequest(status);//serviceUser is the object from class that includes sendFriendRequest method.
    return "OK";
}
```

This is my table in db:

```
+====+================+=====================+===================+
| id | request_status | request_acceptor_id | request_sender_id |
+====+================+=====================+===================+
| 18 | WAITING        | NULL                |                29 |
+----+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| 19 | WAITING        | 23                  |                30 |
+----+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

When i save FriendStatus object(it comes from client) with requestSender which id is 29 and requestAcceptor object which id is 23 hibernate saves it to the column which id is 18.After that when i save second FriendStatus object with requestSender which id is 30 and requestAcceptor object which id is 23,hibernate replaces request_acceptor_id with the NULL in the row which id is 18 and then creates new row in db which request_acceptor_id is 23.But i want that when i add second object,first object don't change.I don't want to replace request_acceptor_id with NULL when i create new column with the same request_acceptor_id.

Comment: Post your code, and clearly explain what you expect it to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: I edited question.Please say if i should add something.

Comment: I already said it: Post your code, and clearly explain what you expect it to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: I edited it again.Is that clear?

Comment: No, because we still have no idea of which objects you create, how you populate them, where the data come from, etc. You should, even for your own ability to test and debug, write an automated test case that reproduces the problem. I would also remove the CascadeType.ALL on the ManyToOne, which makes no sense.

Comment: Objects come from android client.There are just the objects from FriendStatus class and they contain requestSender and requestAcceptor objects from User class.I wrote my classes in the above.

Comment: I think that problem associated with the relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its to do with your cascade setting,

try using the following to save:

```
public void sendFriendRequest(FriendStatus status) {

    User requester=userDao.findOne(status.getRequestAcceptor.getId());
    User sender=userDao.findOne(status.getRequestSender.getId());
    ......
    statusDao.create(status);
    status.getRequestAcceptor(requester);
    status.getRequestSender(sender);
    statusDao.update(status);

}
```

the users that status is carrying have private List sentFriendRequests and private List acceptedFriendRequests; set to empty lists

Ofcause it works out even better if your transaction is outside the whole function then you can use:
sender.getSentFriendRequests().add(status) and reqester.getacceptedFriendRequests().add(status); which i guess was the point of the @OneToMany, Cascade.All

otherwise you can just remove the cascade rules from the collections